# Line with two origins $X$, no injection from $X$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: general-topology

The question is, let $X$ be the union of the set $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and the two-point set $\{ p, q\}$. Topologize $X$ by taking as a basis the collection of all open interval in $R$ that do not contain 0, along with all the sets $f$ the form $(-a, 0) \cup \{p\} \cup (0,a)$ and all the sets of the form $(-a, 0) \cup \{q\} \cup (0,a)$, for $a>0$.

Prove that there is no continuous injection $X \to \mathbb{R^n}$ for any $n \in Z_+$.

I kind of get the intuition of this. Since it has two origins, there is no way to find a injective map. But I am struggling on how to write a formal proof by using this fact. (Or my intuition is actually wrong?)

Great thanks!

Comment: If you have a continuous injection $\iota \colon Y \hookrightarrow Z$, how does the original topology on $Y$ compare to the initial topology with respect to $\iota$?

Comment: By Z, you mean R, right?

Comment: I'm thinking much more general. We would of course apply it to the case $Z = \mathbb{R}^n$ here.

Comment: Sry about that, but I do not really get this, can you explain a little bit more? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How well acquainted are you with the concept of initial topologies?

Comment: learned some, but not very well...

Comment: Okay, let's be more pedestrian then. For the case at hand, let $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous. Look at $\bigl(f(1/n)\bigr)_{n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}}$.

Comment: Great thanks! Since $1/n$ will generate a sequence converges to both p and q, since it is continuous, so we get f(p) = f(q), which contradicts. right?

Comment: It doesn't contradict (we didn't suppose that $f$ is injective), it shows that a continuous function $X\to \mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be injective.